# How to avoid log4j output external modification

Tags: java, logging, hardening

I had a request to find a solution for making a log file secure from editing from the user (not root user) running the JBoss instance of an application (Linux environment)

First idea I had is to use the 'chattr +a' from root user to allow only the appending of new raw in the log file.

But the Log4j file is configured to rotate the file each day and for this reason I suppose that I should repeat the 'chattr' command for each file created everyday. I also not sure that the past day file in its "append only" state can be zipped from rotation.

Any suggestion or alternative way to proceed is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [SyslogAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.html)

This sends all logs to syslogd (which can be on a separate server). You could configure the log files to be non-accessible by the application user, while syslog takes care of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the umask in the environment of the process that is creating the files.  For example, if you want the permissions of new files to be -r--r--r-- (0444), you can set your umask to 222:

```
localhost> umask
77
localhost> touch x
localhost> ls -l 
total 0
-rw-------  1 user1  wheel  0 Mar 17 12:54 x
localhost> umask 222
localhost> touch y
localhost> ls -l 
total 0
-rw-------  1 user1  wheel  0 Mar 17 12:54 x
-r--r--r--  1 user1  wheel  0 Mar 17 12:54 y
```

This will cause any files written from that environment to have these permissions by default, so depending on your other requirements not stated here, this may or may not work for you.